# Изменить расширение файла в REQUEST_URI

Tags: php

Как можно получить php-скриптом часть REQUEST_URI без расширения html, htm, php и т.п?

Или заменить html на cache в этом самом REQUEST_URI?

У меня сейчас такая задача:

Требуется в код динамически генерируемых страниц добавить скрипт, который будет проверять, существование этой страницы в кэше сервера. То есть с расширением cache, а не html.

if (file_exists(--DIR--.'/cache/НАЗВАНИЕ_СТРАНИЦЫ.cache'))

Как я могу получить часть url, которая соответствует этому НАЗВАНИЮ СТРАНИЦЫ?
То есть REQUEST_URI без расширения?

Спасибо!

Пробовала так:

```
if (file_exists(__DIR__.'/cache/filename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]).cache'))
{  
    readfile(__DIR__.'/filename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]).cache'); 
    exit();
```

Но получаю в результате файл с именем: filename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]).cache
Не получает скрипт имя файла.

Аналогичные результаты с

`if (file_exists(__DIR__."/cache/pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_FILENAME).cache"))
    {

        readfile(__DIR__."/cache/pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_FILENAME).cache"); 
        exit();`
Результат - файл с именем :
pathinfo(**FILE**, PATHINFO_FILENAME).cache

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.pathinfo.php

Comment: А в строках в одинарных кавычках переменные не вычисляются.

Comment: просто для информации: уже на протяжении большого количества вопросов вы званимаетесь абсолютно бессмысленной и вредной задачей. динамические страницы не надо кэшировать, и уж тем более таким кустарным способом.

Comment: Возможно, в Ваших проектах это не нужно. А у меня сейчас стоит именно такая задача. На профессионализм я не претендую. У меня вообще гуманитарное образование.

Comment: Дело не в профессионализме, а в умении формулировать задачи. Которое в гуманитарной сфере не менее важно, чем в технической. "кэшировать страницы" - это на задача, а один из вариантов решения. самый неоптимальный.

Comment: Я формулирую задачу в рамках своего владения предметом. Если есть лучшие способы кэшировать динамические страницы, не такие кустарные, подскажите.

Comment: "кэшировать страницы" - это. не. задача.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот такой код у меня прекрасно заработал без всякого дополнительного расширения .cache. В самом начале страницы перед html:

```
<?php
$curr_url = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

if (file_exists(__DIR__."/cache/$curr_url"))
{  
    readfile(__DIR__."/cache/$curr_url"); 
    exit();
} 
ob_start();
?>
```

И в самом конце, после закрывающего хтмл:

```
<?php  
$buffer = ob_get_contents(); 

$fp = fopen(__DIR__."/cache/$curr_url", 'w'); 

fwrite($fp, $buffer);
ob_end_flush(); 
fclose($fp); 
?>
```

Все файлы сохраняются в папку cache с расширением php или html (смотря как была запрошена страница). И отдаются следующему пользователю из cache без запроса к БД.

Ура, товарищи!

И зря Вы, господа, минусовали ответ Grigory Fedorinov. Ибо он абсолютно правильно предложил использовать basename вместо filename.

Answer (score -1):

```
$filename=basename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); //Получаем название страницы без расширения
$filename_md5 = md5($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); //Получаем хеш-код страницы (32-значный уникальный код для страницы) для уникальности страницы в кеше.
// $filename."_".$filename_md5 - Человеко-читаемое и уникальное хранение страницы в кеше
//При записи в кеш в начале страницы пишется html-комментарий с $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] если необходимо получить полное расположение страницы на сайте    
if (file_exists(__DIR__."/cache/{$filename."_".$filename_md5}.cache")){
    echo file_get_contents(__DIR__."/{$filename."_".$filename_md5}.cache"); 
    exit();
}
```

Comment: К сожалению, не работает

Comment: Григорий, действительно, мне был нужен basename! Правда, хеш-код мне не понадобился. Я в этом ничего не понимаю. Сделала без него.

Comment: Хозяин - барин. В данном случае хозяйка.